# Equivalent to @EJB annotation for local variables?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, annotations, ejb

EJBs in Hibernate. Is there any equivalent to dependency injection

```
@EJB(mappedName = FoobarServiceInterface.JNDI_NAME_LOCAL)
private FoobarServiceInterface foo;
```

when `foo` is a local variable?

I managed to use either @EJB annotation for class members or

```
FoobarServiceInterface bar = (FoobarServiceInterface)InitialContext.doLookup(FoobarServiceInterface.JNDI_NAME_LOCAL);
```

to do a lookup, if `bar` is a local variable.

However, I wonder if there is any annotation that can be used on local variables such as @EJB for class member variables.

Answer (score 0):

Whats the benefit of using it as local variable?
EJB can be shared by many requests/threads and lookup is not a free process, so it is usually recommended to use it as class member instead of local variable.

Comment: I'm refactoring existing code and it used local variables. So I just wondered, if there is any annotation for that case.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such annotation. According to the ejb3.1 specification:

> 4.3.2 Dependency Injection
>   ... If a session bean makes use of dependency injection, the container injects these references after the bean instance is created, and
>   before any business methods are invoked on the bean instance...

Therefore, the annotations used by the container to inject dependencies (@EJB, @Resources, @Inject) are applicable only to certain [Targets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html). e.g.: @Target(value={TYPE,**METHOD**,**FIELD**})